# Deleting AWS S3 Resource with Resource URL - Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Is there a way to delete a resource from AWS S3 using the java sdk by URL?

I know you can delete a resource using a bucket name and keyName like this:

```
s3client.deleteObject(new DeleteObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName));
```

The issue is that I only have access to the resourceURL, so I would need to manipulate the string to extract the bucketname and keyname.

But if there was a way to delete by passing the url would be much cleaner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way to simply pass the URL.

There's this, though:

> **AmazonS3URI**
>
> `public AmazonS3URI(String str)`
>
> Creates a new AmazonS3URI by parsing the given string. String will be URL encoded before generating the URI.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3URI.html

You can call `getKey` and `getBucket` on it to extract the strings you need.  It's still messy, but at least it looks like you don't have to write your own parser.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Just for anyone else reading this in future. With the URL, I deleted an object like this: 

    AmazonS3URI as3uri = new AmazonS3URI(*URL TO OBJECT*);
    s3Client.deleteObject(as3uri.getBucket(), as3uri.getKey());

Comment: any info on how to do the same in javascript my friend?